# How to view interactive PDF online

Tags: flash, pdf, interactive

I have an interactive pdf that I am trying to get onto my website. Aside from taking a really long time to load (any suggestions) it is not working properly in the preview mode, as of now it just shows a symbol for flash. Is there anyway to make it show up in preview mode without downloading it automatically?

http://aishconnections.com/2013report.pdf

Comment: *preview mode* of which application?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pdf.js to preview your pdf without it downloading. Works in all major browsers including mobile devices.